# Why won't my wordpress action function save to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have added the following function to the bottom of my child themes functions.php

```
function save_source( $post_id ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->insert( 'wptest_traffic', array( 'source' => 'value1' ), array( '%s' ) );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_source' );
```

and have a database table such as
wptest_traffic

```
Name    Type                 Collation     Attributes   Null    Default
source  varchar(1000)   latin1_swedish_ci               No  None
```

Yet when I create new posts, nothing gets added to the db table.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: give some sample records on ur `wptest_traffic` table

Comment: What does $wpdb->insert return ? false ? zero ?

Comment: Are you sure your function is even getting called?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest that your table name is probably wrong.  You should always bring in the `$table_prefix`, and use it.  `global $table_prefix;' and then in your insert `$wpdb->insert($table_prefix . 'wptest_traffic', ....`

Comment: cale_b, how can I check?

Comment: cale_b, Tried your second suggestion, no luck

Comment: id say you have `wptest_wptest_traffic` as your table name now. Really you should be able to debug this. something like `echo $wpdb->last_error; exit;` after you try and insert to the db. Your code looks correct so it can only be either the tablename is incorrect, the mysql rules for the column does not support what you are entering,  the save post hook has not been called or a function is hooked to save_post with a priority of less than 10 with a redirect (it wont be this)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you update a post? Does this function even get fired up on update/save ?

you could also try (not tested):
[wp_insert_post_data](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data)
and [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post)

I would also check what does     `$wpdb->insert_id` returns after/if the function gets fired up.

Comment: Not really an answer.  A string of guesses / suggestions, which really should be a *comment*.